# Android studio layouts howto make prompt/hint before EdiText

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in a kotlin project, and have been searching for some documentation about the screen layout.

What i want to do is very rudimentairy i guess. I want is to put a label/prompt/text before a EditText.

In html i would program something like this:

```
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
</form>
```

And get the a result like this:

First name: ___________

All i can find is a "android:hint=". But it only fills the View if there is nothing in it.

Should one add extra (plainText) elements for each label ? and how should one contstrain it to the EditText ? or is there some kind of grouping ?

**Update after received answers**

After reading the answers i understand that you have to roll your own solution. (I am still fighting with androidstudio because it sorts the xml elements so they are not always where i put them.)

I do not use a TextInputLayout (i hope this is allowed) which makes it all quite simple. So this is my solution for now:

We link the TextView ("Date of Birth") to the parent layout:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/dobLabel2"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
        android:labelFor="@id/dobInputText"
        android:text="Date of Birth"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

and we link the EditText to the TextView

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/dobInputText"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:hint="Day/Month/Year"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dobLabel2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dobLabel2" />
```

If you play with the layout_contraints you can position the the EditText also to the left of the label.

Thanks for all the input, i think i can solve my problem now.

Comment: `Should one add extra (plainText) elements for each label ?` depends on your layout, so impossible to say, based on what you described you probably will just add some components to the front. typically, android uses text input layouts to handle this type of thing, https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields

Comment: I would add the TextInputLayout around the TextInputEditText and move the constraints there; It won't change "anything" as far as the functioning you're used to. You can pretend it's an "edit text wrapper" (which it is to be honest). As for the comment "fighting with androidstudio because it sorts the xml elements" -> Go to Android Studio Prefernces, Editor -> Code Style -> Xml -> Arrangement (tab) and change the order, or...at the bottom: "Force Rearrange" -> Never. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android EditText (now often used as a combination of `TextInputLayout` containing one (and only one) `TextInputEditText`) can display a Hint, but only while the view has no focus/content.

If you want to provide a better description on what a particular EditText is for, for many reasons (accessibility, often neglected, is not the only one), you may want to provide an extra `TextView` positioned anywhere you consider it ok to add the extra information needed to better describe the EditText.

The main thing to keep in mind, is to provide this `TextView` with the `labelFor` attribute, as described [in the Android documentation](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6378120?hl=en).

If you're reading this and wondering *but why do I have to provide an extra Textview to describe, why not just use the hint, android is horrible!!!*, keep in mind that the Hint is good for different reasons, but not for describing what the field is about.

E.g.: Imagine you're asking for a Date of Birth. You may be tempted to write this: (note this is a **simplified version** obviously):

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/dobInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/dobInputText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Date of Birth" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And you'd be mostly ok, but then your designer comes in and says, well, we also want to show the *Format* that we accept, for e.g.: DAY/MONTH/YEAR...

Now you're going to change the *hint* to be:

`android:hint="Date of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY)`

And you'd again, be ok, but for accessibility users... this doesn't *read* very efficiently nor is very clear. You also get back from your designer who says: "but I don't want the (DD/MM/YYYY) part to be visible after the user focuses or types something..."

And so on and so forth.

The *correct* (according to Google, Material Design, and who knows what), is to provide an extra `TextView` that accompanies the TextInput combos:
(again, keep in mind this is pseudo-code, when in doubt, read the documentation)

```
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/dobLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date of Birth"
    android:labelFor="@id/dobInputText />
    
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/dobInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/dobInputText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Day/Month/Year" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Do *not* provide `contentDescription` on those views because they will likely interfere with TalkBack/Accessibility. These are the *conventions* that Android set in place, you may or may not like them, but this is how it's *expected* to be done.

Do *I* think EditText should be a better widget and handle this better for you? Yes. Does it matter what I think? Nope.

Comment: Martin, wow... very detailed answer, Thanks. I have edited my question with the solution i came up with. I do not use TextInputLayout is there a reason to use it ?

Comment: The combo of TextInputEditText and TextInputLayout is usually better suited for Material Design since it handles the space around the edit text (errors are shown below), the animation(s) of the hint when the focus is gained or lost, and the animations/operations of the various accessories (clear buttons, stylings, etc.) among others. It is _the_ recommended way to do it now. I refer back to my last paragraph :)))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add one more textview before adding edit text. The hint is used for displaying messages in edittext.

Comment: Maulik, thanks. There is no options to bundle it like html ? I have to use isolated/separate elements

Comment: I don't know it can be used or not but we should prefer more xml tags there. You can check this : 
https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/06/how-to-display-html-code-in-android.html